# Is it possible to forward emails to rotating email addresses automatically in Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Is it possible to forward emails to rotating email addresses automatically in Microsoft Outlook?

I am trying to find a solution for randomly assigning incoming emails to 3 different users and looking for a solution that isn't forwarding each email to all 3 emails.

Thank you for any guidance on rules, delegation, etc to solve this!

Comment: I have never used it but Outlook rules [can be scripted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/create-script-for-rule-wizard-in-outlook) which *may* give you the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Normal rules cannot do this. The reason is that every time a rule is executed, there is no way to know what happened before. It is possible to create a macro that does this, but it is very hard.

Comment: randomly assigning is not the same as assigning in rotation

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I have attempted a few VBA approaches and looked into the script rule (currently disabled so likely not an option).  My intention was not to get free scripting but to understand if it was possible.  I have written and successfully executed components of what I am trying to accomplish but it is tying the components together to work holistically that I am struggling with.  (Ie success with loop logic in excel to grab the email, successful with forwarding but forwarding based on the loop from excel is failing.  Again appreciate the comments!

Answer (score 1):

**Forward emails to rotating email addresses automatically in Microsoft Outlook**

Microsoft Outlook VBA macro to forward emails in a rotation to x# of people.
Please follow the instructions below:

1. Open Outlook and press "Alt + F11" to open the VBA editor.
2. In the VBA editor, expand the "Microsoft Outlook Objects" folder and double-click on "ThisOutlookSession" to open the code window for the Outlook session.
3. Paste the code below into the code window.
4. Change the email addresses to the actual emails you want to forward to in the Array.
5. Adjust the number (Mod) to the correct number of emails in the array, currently set to 4.
6. After pasting the code, save the macro and close the VBA editor.
7. Restart Outlook for the macro to take effect.
   With this simple macro, incoming emails will be forwarded in a rotation to the 4 specified email addresses. The rotation starts from the first address in the array and moves sequentially.
   Please note that this macro assumes there are no specific conditions or filters for forwarding emails. It forwards all incoming emails to the rotation recipients.
   Copy and paste as indicated the following code:

```
 Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items

 Private currentIndex As Integer

 Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application

    Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace

    Dim inboxFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application

    Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set inboxFolder = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Set inboxItems = inboxFolder.Items

    currentIndex = 0

 End Sub

 Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim forwardEmail As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim rotationEmails As Variant

   
    ' Define the rotation email addresses

    rotationEmails = Array("email1@domain.com", "email2@domain.com", "email3@domain.com", "email4@domain.com")

   
    Set forwardEmail = Item.Forward

    forwardEmail.Recipients.Add rotationEmails(currentIndex)

    forwardEmail.Send

   
    ' adjust the rotation index – change the Mod number to the number of emails in the rotation

    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) Mod 4

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, the rules cannot meet your request. If you want to use inbox rule to forward mails, you need create specific filter to forward mails to the specific users or group. It is not random.

For example:

[image]

At present, Outlook seems cannot do this thing, you may need to seek for an expert on scripts and maybe they will provide some solution.